# Updating the upper bound of a daterange to infinity

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

The syntax of how to update just the upper bound of a daterange column has me stumped.

I would like the lower bound to remain unchanged and to update only the upper bound of a daterange column (e.g. timespan)to 'infinity' if it contains a certain bound (e.g. 2013-12-31).

This is as far as i have gotten:

```
UPDATE table
SET timespan = daterange(lower(timespan),upper(infinity)::daterange)
WHERE (upper(timespan) = '2013-12-31'::daterange);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't tell us what error you get, but there are three problems as far as I can tell:

First: the two casts to a `daterange` are wrong. The bounds of a `daterange` are `date` values. So you would need to cast them to `date` not to `daterange`, e.g.

```
where upper(timespan) = '2013-12-31'::date
```

The second problem is the use of `upper(infinity)`. Again `infinity` is not a range, just a point in time, so using `upper()` on it doesn't work.

And `infinity` must be enclosed in single quotes, you can use it as a keyword there

```
UPDATE the_table
   SET timespan = daterange(lower(timespan),'infinity')
WHERE (upper(timespan) = date '2013-12-31');
```

I *think* that setting the upper bound to `null` would have the same effect. Not sure if there is a subtle difference between `null` and `infinity` as one of the bounds.

Comment: There is a difference between null and infinity as a range bound. The infinity bound is less than null. [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2626).

Comment: `infinity` is basically an alias for the highest possible date value. `SELECT date 'infinity'` returns `292278994-08-17`.